# Discrete Mathematics Enumeration problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

It is assumed that Valley street has 4 people living alone, 8 couples, 4 families of 3 people, 5 families of 4 people, 6 families of 5 people and 3 families of 6 people. How many ways are there to distribute these inhabitants in the 30 houses of the street?

I got this question that i've been stuck on for a while, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: But what are the conditions? Does a family has to live together and alone in a house or what? If that's the case then isn't there $30!$ number of ways?

Comment: @Letsintegreat The conditions hasn't been specified but I'm guessing a family takes one house, a couple one house, a person living alone one house etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have $30$ houses and $30$ 'families'.

So you can choose a house for the first family in $30$ ways.

There are then $29$ houses for the next family and so on.

In total there are $30\times 29\times 28 \times ... \times 1=30! $ ways.